# No Water but Water supply valve is ON

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I have water shut-off valve (*all-or-nothing*) for an outside hose. I see the valve is ON, but the water is not coming in outside hose.

Edit:

The valve is under kitchen sink in the Main floor. This is a walkout basement house and the outdoor faucet  is in the backyard.

It was never turned off during last winter, so I was wrong.

Although cold water is coming through  to the Kitchen Faucet.

[image]

Comment: Where is this valve located? What kind of foundation does your house/apartment have - is it a slab, basement or crawl space? Do you see or hear water running somewhere else when you opened the outside valve? Did you open the outside tap as well? Please [edit] your question to provide all these answers.

Comment: Turn the main water supply off, then remove and inspect the shutoff valve. The washer might be in the wrong position. If the valve is fine, gently turn the water supply on, and make sure the water is coming through.

Comment: if you look at the picture, there is round screw on the right side of the valve, when I loose or unscrew it, the water leaks, what that means ?

Comment: Are you sure that is the main shutoff I see the label but it would be unusual to have things on the supply side of a shutoff

Comment: Yes that is the Main shut off for just exterior faucet

Comment: Is there any chance the water in the faucet outside is frozen?  Either way the faucet needs to be open before switching on the water, trapped air can be enough to stop the flow (although it's relatively unlikely...).

Comment: If you undo the screw on the side of the valve and water leaks out, that means you shouldn't be loosening that screw.

Comment: If you undo that screw and water comes out it means you have water on one side of the cutoff valve.

Comment: I'll guess the screw-cap on that ball valve is a bleeder port. A bleeder provides a way of draining something. In this case one could close the ball valve, open the hose bibb faucet outdoors, and open the bleeder port. The bleeder would allow air into the pipe so that, presumably, water in the pipe would drain to the outside and eliminate the possibility of those pipes freezing during the winter.

Comment: I think Greg Hill got the screw part correctly. You can now shut the valve, and loosen the screw, the water shall spring out, if not, let it drain for a while to verify there is no problem in the supply line. Then turn the valve on, if no water gets through, you need to call a plumber to check the valve.

Comment: For future reference, most people think of the "main" shutoff as one that would shut off water to the whole house. Most people would consider this an "inside" shutoff for your outside valve. You shut this off in the late fall & open the outside tap to drain the line so that your outside valve (and the pipe to it) don't have any water in them to freeze.

Comment: After a lots of research and you guys help. I am pretty sure its Frost Free Bib faucet That I have outside, because I left a garden timer hose during winter and water was not able to drained completely. I might have to replace the bib. Damn!!